# Why am I unable to see this variable in my view?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

So here's the relevant segment from my router:

**app.js**

```
.state('app.browse', {
    url: "/browse/:question",
    controller: 'QCtrl',
    resolve: {
      question: function($stateParams, qService){
        console.log(qService.getQuestion($stateParams.question).q);
        return qService.getQuestion($stateParams.question).q;
      }
    },
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: "templates/browse.html"
    }
  }
})

/* QSERVICE HERE  */
.factory('qService', function() {
var questions = [ {'q': "text text"} ];
return {
    questions: questions,
    getQuestion: function(index) {
      return questions[index]
    }
  }
})
```

**controllers.js**

```
.controller('QCtrl', function($scope, question){
  $scope.questions = qService.questions;
  $scope.question = question;
})
```

Which finds exactly what I'm looking for as demonstrated by the console log.

However in my browser view, I am unable to grab the `question` variable!

**browser.html**

```
<ion-view view-title="Browse">
            {{question}}
</ion-content>
```

Which always displays as empty! Why is this happening, and how do I resolve it?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but shouldn't `$scope.question` be defined somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resolve will not bind question unto your controller.

In your controller do this

```
.controller('QCtrl', function ($scope, question) {
   $scope.question = question;
})
```

In addition - in your state object, the question is being passed incorrectly. Correction:

```
.state('app.browse', {
    url: "/browse/:question",
    resolve: {
      question: function($stateParams, qService){
        return qService.getQuestion($stateParams.question);
      }
    },
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: "templates/browse.html",
        controller: 'QCtrl',
      }
    }
  })
```

You're also missing templateUrl in your state object. Update this to reflect where the the template is and it should be good to go :)

Comment: Hey so I tied this, and this doesn't seem to fix it. I've pasted some more code above, can you take a look?

Comment: Can you post your controller?

Comment: Can you please post your qService.

Comment: Done! Sorry I realized the previous update hung. You should see all the relevant code now.

Comment: And I assume $stateparams.question === 0?

Comment: Yes - fair assumption. It was pretty big, so I just chopped it down to one element.

Comment: You are missing your templateUrl in your state object.

Comment: Sorry about that - I accidentally over wrote some code. That was there already,  look again?

Comment: Sorry for the sloppiness with putting up that code!

Comment: No, you can't do that way.  Each view takes in it's templateUrl and Ctrl

Comment: Ahh perfect. Thank you for bearing with me, I'm still figuring out Angular.js. I'm going to edit your answer to reflect the fix. Thanks!